# FreeRTOS ignores osDelay [STM32]

Tags: stm32, crc, freertos, hal, canopen

I am new here, but have often benefited from questions and their results.

Now I have a problem that I can not solve for days. It is about a STM32L431RCT6 with FreeRTOS. There are 3 tasks running on it. Two of them are dedicated to processing [CanOpenNode](https://github.com/CANopenNode/CanOpenSTM32) (1 to send data, 1 to receive). One is a custom controller. The code works as it is, but when I enable the CRC unit (MX_CRC_Init()) the problem appears. With the CRC unit enabled, only the task to receive the data from Canopen is executed. The other tasks are set to "Ready". What I notice is that the osDelay() used in the receive task seems to be ignored. It doesn't seem to matter if I use osDelay(1) or osDelay(10000).

```
void start_CO_rec_Thread(void *argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN start_CO_TI_Thread */

  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
    canopen_app_interrupt();
    osDelay(1);
  }
  osThreadTerminate(NULL);
  /* USER CODE END start_CO_TI_Thread */
}
```

Something else is added. If I remove functions and variables in the task by starting an own controller, the processing of the tasks works again. Now I have concluded that the tasks need more stack memory. But this is also not the solution of the puzzle...

Working Code:

```
void Start_Controller(void *argument)
{
    Sensor = new DS18B20(htim6);
    Regler = new Smithpredictor(Sensor);
//  osTimerStart(LifetimerHandle, 1000);
      for(;;)
      {
          if (global_state==4)
          actual_Temperatur = Regler->run(target_Temperature);
          osDelay(MBC_intervall_s*1000);
      }
      osThreadTerminate(NULL);
}
```

Not Working Code:

```
void Start_Controller(void *argument)
{
    Sensor = new DS18B20(htim6);
    Regler = new Smithpredictor(Sensor);
        osTimerStart(LifetimerHandle, 1000);
      for(;;)
      {
          if (global_state==4)
          actual_Temperatur = Regler->run(target_Temperature);
          osDelay(MBC_intervall_s*1000);
      }
      osThreadTerminate(NULL);
}
```

I hope someone has an idea how to proceed or can help me. Even if it is just another way to further identify the problem. Maybe I have also committed some stupidity, I am unfortunately not a computer scientist.

Comment: `Sensor = new DS18B20(htim6);` Two questions: Do you realy need the dynamic memory allocations? Have you verified, that you implementation of dynamic memory allocation works correctly with RTOS?

Comment: I am now also unsure about this...freertos also allocates memory dynamically. Possibly something crashes there...I will allocate the two Instazen once statically.